# Can javascript rewrite an external file

Tags: javascript

I am working on a program where you would chose a directory and than the website will save data there. I know I could do this with cookies but I am challenging myself to do do it differently.

I would really appreciate help with this. Is it possible? If so how would I do it?

Comment: JS doesn't have access to the file system, security measures.

Comment: HTML5 local storage. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: You mean a directory on the server?

Comment: @tymeJV Thanks, that is very helpful. Can PHP do It?

Comment: You need server-side code and AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because JavaScript has no access to your filesystem.

The only thing you could do it trigger a filedownload from within JavaScript. But in this case the browser handles the whole download (maybe without selecting a directory).

And the other point is that your server has to serve the data. So you need another roundtrip and maybe sending some user information to the server is necessary.